# Redirect to custom login page in sitefinity 5

Tags: sitefinity-5

In my Sitefinity 5.0 site, I had a custom login page for frontend users. When unauthenticated users tried to access a restricted page, I redirected them to our front-end login page using custom errors.

In Sitefinity 5.1, attempting to access a page for which you don't have permission simply results in Sitefinity redirecting the user to the internal backend "Login to manage the site" login.

Is there a way to configure Sitefinity to use my login page instead of the built-in backend login page?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible for you to upgrade to at least Sitefinity 5.2? Apparently in that version a new event was introduced that fires on failed logins that you can intercept in Global.asax to redirect as needed to any page you wish.

More info is available here: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/stefani-tacheva-s-blog/2013/02/01/redirect-unauthorized-users-to-a-custom-page

I hope this is helpful!